# Run commands in the python terminal through ansible playbook

Tags: python, nltk, ansible

I'm new to ansible but I'm trying to run a few commands inside the python terminal through an ansible playbook. Specifically, I want to download a corpus.

```
$python
>import nltk
>nltk.download
> ~ d (download)
> ~ book
> ~ q (quit)
>quit()
```

Currently, my playbook file creates an virtualenv that installs nltk through a `requirements.txt` but I don't know how to get the specific nltk feature without manually downloading it.

I ran across this line in my search, `python -m nltk.downloader all` which satisfies my program but it's a download of a lot of unnecessary things, taking up memory. However, in the meantime, I did try it out by running:

```
- name: Get the nltk corpus
  shell: "python -m nltk.downloader all"
```

but this erred with the message:

```
TASK [Get the nltk corpus]*****************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "python -m nltk.downloader book", "delta": "0:00:00.016227", "end": "2016-12-29 20:06:09.156953", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-12-29 20:06:09.140726", "stderr": "/usr/bin/python: No module named nltk", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Are there any suggestions on how to make either the above code work, or another method to achieve my goal with getting the specific nltk feature via ansible?

---

**UPDATE**:

Just to be a little clearer, I'm trying to run a command that would work normally in a python shell outside of the sell in an ansible playbook.

For example, the line `nltk.download("book")` works exactly as I need it to inside the python terminal. But I need to run this without entering the terminal manually and through a task in the ansible playbook.

I've tried something similar to this and although it compiles, it doesn't actually download the book corpus as I need it to.

```
- name: Get the "book" nltk corpus
  shell: "/usr/local/venv/bin/python -m nltk.downloader book"
```

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#module-nltk.downloader) and [source code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/downloader.html) hints that you can download individual modules:

> Individual packages can be downloaded by calling the download() function with a single argument, giving the package identifier for the package that should be downloaded

If `book` is a package in your example (I'm not familiar with NLTK), try:

```
- name: Get the nltk corpus
  shell: "python -m nltk.downloader book"
```

Comment: That's a wonderful suggestion that I will try but before I can modify that statement, I need to be able to make it run. The code in the ansible playbook does not compile. (I've edited and added the error message above)

Comment: If you install pip packages into virtualenv, don't forget to `chdir` (there is a parameter for `shell` module) there and run local python interpreter and not default python.

Comment: That worked! I had to run the path to the python that existed in the virtualenv explicitly `/path/in/venv/to/**python** -m nltk.downloader book`
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The command `nltk.download()` is for downloading nltk **data**: corpora and trained models for things like the POS tagger. To use it, you must already have the nltk code installed, i.e. you must be able to successfully run `import nltk`. You say that you are running in a virtualenv with the `nltk` module available,  but your error message suggests otherwise: `/usr/bin/python: No module named nltk`. If that's the real problem, you first need to sort it out (and/or correct your question).

Assuming you can launch Python so that the `import nltk` statement succeeds, you  can download a corpus (your stated aim) with, e.g., `nltk.import("brown")` for the Brown corpus. (Of course this must be run after `import nltk`.) To download all the resources mentioned in the NLTK book, use `nltk.import("book")`.

Comment: I have successfully downloaded nltk, and can `import nltk` fine. That was not the problem I stated in the question.  The questions was how to automate this in the ansible script. As in the solution will be ansible code.

Comment: Have you tried to run `nltk.download("brown")` in your python session? The point is, if you do it this way you don't need to feed responses to an interactive GUI pop-up.

Comment: This works fine in the python session but my goal is to have this statement run without me manually opening a python session and running it there. I want ansible to open a python session and run it and then exit that python session.

Comment: It sounds like your question either has nothing to do with ansible or it has nothing to do with the nltk. If you can run one python command, you can run them all. If you don't, you already know how to run a shell command in ansible, don't you? Try `python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('brown')"`